# How to find files that contain one criterion but exclude a different criterion

Tags: grep, find

I have a tree of source code and I am looking to find all files that contain a certain word and must not contain a second word. This, because I need to update older files to include some newer code.

I know I can use find, but I feel like if I try to chain grep statements it won't work because the second grep statement is going to be searching the results of the first and then I got lost.

I tried:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec grep -Hl "ABC" {} \; | grep -L "123"
```

And this totally did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

Since the exit status of `grep` indicates whether or not it found a match, you should be able to test that directly as a `find` predicate (with the necessary negation, `!` or `-not`) e.g.

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" \( -exec grep -q "ABC" {} \; ! -exec grep -q "123" {} \; \) -print
```

`-q` makes `grep` exit silently on the first match - we don't need to hear from it because we let `find` print the filename.

Comment: Note that it runs at least one and up to two `grep`s per C file. `-q` already stops at the first match. `-m1` (a GNU extension) won't make any difference.

Comment: @steeldriver:  I believe that you could leave out the `\(` and the `\)`.

Comment: Is grep "123" applied on results from first find/grep couple ?

Answer (score 8):

Since you're already using GNU extensions:

```
find . -type f -size +2c -name "*.c" -exec grep -l --null ABC {} + |
  xargs -r0 grep -L 123
```

If you want to do something else with those files:

```
find . -type f -size +2c -name "*.c" -exec grep -l --null ABC {} + |
  xargs -r0 grep -L --null 123 | xargs -r0 sh -c '
    for file do
      something with "$file"
    done' sh {} +
```

Or with `zsh` or `bash`:

```
find . -type f -size +2c -name "*.c" -exec grep -l --null ABC {} + |
  xargs -r0 grep -L --null 123 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    something with "$file"
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

For complex constrains, I prefer using a programming language: Awk

```
find -name '*.c' \
   -exec awk -v RS="\0" '/ABC/ && !/123/{print FILENAME}' {} \;
```